# Making an image change from one to the next in 2 seperate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create two divs with a rotating image in on my webpage, these change to another image after a certain amount of seconds and there are 3 images to display. At the moment I am just trying to get the mechanics of this working using the code below, but although its simple I can not get it working. the code is the same as what I have used before however this time it does not want to work. I did it last, years agao, and I have completely forgotten how and research has not helped.

My code is below. In case this problem is site specific I have also included a [livelink HERE](http://www.airforceadvice.com/new.html) which I shall remove once the question is answered. ***THE TWO DIVS ARE THE RED AND YELLOW BOXES.***

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
var rotators = [
{ id: 'advert1', images: ['http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_graph.png'], selectedIndex: 0 },
{ id: 'advert2', images: ['http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis_big.jpg', 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis2_big.jpg', 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis3_big.jpg'], selectedIndex: 0 }
];

var updateImages = function() {
for (var i=0; i < rotators.length; i++) {
var rotator = rotators[i];
rotator.selectedIndex++;
if (rotator.selectedIndex >= rotator.images.length) {
    rotator.selectedIndex = 0;
}
document.getElementById(rotator.id).src = rotator.images[rotator.selectedIndex];
}
};
var timer = setInterval(updateImages, 1000);
         </script>
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="advert1"></div>
  <div id="advert2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set the div src. you need to have an image (img) element inside each div and then to set the image src.

```
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <img id="advert1" alt="" src.../>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="advert2" alt="" src.../>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Another option will be to set the div background image using the style property or class property (both using CSS sets with JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code in Google Chrome, I see the following error in the console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined | new.html:204

It seems like you forgot to include the jQuery in your html page.

You can get it from a CDN on the following page: http://code.jquery.com/

Another problem is that you're trying to update an img but your DOM element is a div.
You should replace the following code:

```
    <div id="main">
      <div id="advert1"></div>
      <div id="advert2"></div>
    </div>
```

With:

```
    <div id="main">
      <img src="" id="advert1" />
      <img src="" id="advert2" />
    </div>
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks does it matter which jquery i use?

Comment: I updated my answer to correct another mistake. Regarding the jQuery version, you should use jQuery 1.x if you want to support IE < 9, otherwise you can use jQuery 2.x

Answer (score 1):

The javascript is executed where you write, if you write before element then the element does not exist.

You can attach code to onReady event of document or puts code after element.